# Unanswered questions relies on one selected tag only

Tags: bug, unanswered-questions

- https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/php
- https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/php+oop

They look similar.

Comment: Try [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php+oop?sort=unanswered&pageSize=30).

Comment: @remyabel questions section works fine.

Comment: Ah I see. The difference is `unanswered` shows all questions without answers. `?sort=unanswered` shows questions with no upvoted answers.

Comment: How about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/php+and+oop)?

Comment: It works... Never know about 'and' : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that by default the unanswered URL does [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) **or** [oop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oop). You can add `and` to the url to force it to show only questions tagged with both.

https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/php+and+oop shows 279 questions instead of 67,536.

Comment: You are right. Last question: is it *by Design*? Cannot find mentioning in help center.

Comment: I wonder if they could make `php++oop` work the same way, that's a little more intuitive and easier to type.